# Does Optimus work with Quadro cards?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, workstation, optimus

I am soon to be purchasing my next mobile computer, which will be a powerful desktop replacement that can do anything I throw at it; which will be quite a lot.  Mobility, power, extensibility, and battery life are all equally important considerations for this machine, so I have decided on a 15" mobile workstation with 3K display and a NVidia Quadro card, such as the [Dell M4800](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/precision-m4800-workstation/pd), or the (upcoming) [Lenovo W540](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/w-series/w540/).

My research in to these machines suggests that in the Dell at least, Optimus does not work.  This is a problem for me as I will be using this machine extensively on the road and battery life is a concern.

Further research has shown that some people are saying that Optimus does not work with *any* Quadro card.  I've not been able to find anything about this on Nvidia's site.  Is this true, that Optimus doesn't work with Quadro cards?

Note that I'll only need to use Optimus when I'm not plugged in, and I won't be connected to external monitors at that time either.

Answer (score 1):

Quadro and Optimus do work as a post [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/392864-33-mobile-nvidia-quadro-activating-optimus) shows a in-correctly working Quadro. I suppose Optimus should work fine with Quadro if correctly configured. An article on [Endgadget](http://www.engadget.com/2011/02/23/nvidia-debuts-new-slew-of-quadro-mobile-gpus-each-sporting-opti/) shows that Quadro mobile GPUs supported Optimus right from their launch.